# Оформление перечисления

Tags: перечисление

Такая ясность невозможна без обращения (а) к специфике современности и (б) к философии.
Возможно ли такое оформление перечисления?

Comment: Обычно в списках каждый пункт начинается с новой строки. А Вам именно в одну строку нужно все расположить?

Comment: Да. Это всё внутри большого текста. Оформление в виде нормального перечня не подходит.

Comment: Без знаков препинания тут точно не обойтись.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Такая ясность невозможна без обращения а) к специфике современности и б) к философии.***

Это возможный вариант, если оставить союз И между элементами перечня. Я считаю, что он не позволяет поставить другие знаки ни после слова "обращения", ни между однородными членами.

Ср.: ***Такая ясность невозможна без обращения: а) к специфике современности;  б) к философии.***

Об оформлении перечней есть статья [11 правил оформления списков](https://infogra.ru/typography/11-pravil-oformleniya-spiskov-i-perechnej), но Вашего случая (оформление в строчку) в статье нет. Принято каждый элемент перечня писать с новой строки.

Answer (score 3):

Вот что нашлось в [Справочнике издателя и автора](https://books.google.ee/books?id=N2p6GFY7PXkC&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5,%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C.%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80.:%20%20%D0%9D%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0:&source=bl&ots=df6C1zxTNA&sig=wbIzsdIb1v9cuEJ1mCxD9pTyE6A&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU0u3qwKzfAhUB_iwKHSgEAuoQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C.%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80.%3A%20%20%D0%9D%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%3A&f=false) А. Э. Мильчина.

**2.3. Форма текста, предваряющего перечень**

**2.3.1. Рекомендуемая форма**
Перед перечнем обычно ставят обобщающее слово (существительное, глагол, прилагательное, в зависимости от ведущего слова элементов перечня). Напр.:

Ниткошвейные машины по степени автоматизации выполняемых операций делят на следующие виды: 1) полуавтоматы (с ручной подачей тетрадей в швейное и ручным выполнением некоторых других операций); 2) автоматы (c автоматической подачей тетрадей и программным управлением).

**2.3.2. Допустимая форма**
Если обобщающее слово ввести трудно или если при этом придется употребить много дополнительных слов, можно завершить предваряющий текст глаголом или расщепленным сказуемым, даже если ведущее слово элементов перечня – другая часть речи, а предлог, которым этот глагол (расщепленное сказуемое) управляет, перенести в состав 1-го элемента перечня. Напр.:

Ниткошвейные машины по степени автоматизации делятся: 1) на полуавтоматы...; 2) автоматы…
Обратить внимание: а) на правильность, б) однородность, в) целесообразность.

(Так называемый висячий предлог не рекомендуется.)

Ваше предложение, думаю, должно выглядеть так (то есть без повтора предлога):
**Такая ясность невозможна без обращения: а) к специфике современности, б) философии.**

Есть [мнение](http://genling.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000026/st034.shtml): нумеровать или литеровать (обозначать буквами) целесообразно прежде всего те перечни, которые надо запомнить или полностью, или в определенном порядке.

Answer (score 2):

Если пункта всего два, может без перечня обойтись?
"Такая ясность невозможна без обращения к философии, а также специфике современности"